# JS: write a join function using reduce method ... console.log of function returns incorrect output

Tags: javascript, string, function, logging, reduce

I want to write a join function using reduce. It takes two arguments, an array to operate on and a delimiter. The function will return a string.  The delimiter can be optional, if not given should default to ',' .

Below is my code:

```
var arrayOfStrings = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function join (arr, delim=',') {

  return arr.reduce((a,e) => {
    return a+e+delim;
  }, '')
}
```

When I invoke the function below the output 'a,b,c,' looks right:

```
join(arrayOfStrings)
```

But when I invoke the function within a console log the output returns incorrectly;

```
console.log('should join elements in array together into a string: ', 
  join(arrayOfStrings) === 'a,b,c'
);
```

output:

```
should join elements in array together into a string:  false
=> undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `'a,b,c,'` looks right

No, because your current code results in a trailing comma, as you can see there, but you expect there to be no trailing comma, as it looks from your test:

```
console.log('should join elements in array together into a string: ', 
  join(arrayOfStrings) === 'a,b,c'
);
```

I'd conditionally add the delimiter only if the accumulator already has something in it (thus adding no delimiter on the first iteration):

```js
var arrayOfStrings = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function join(arr, delim = ',') {
  return arr.reduce((a, item) => a ? a + delim + item : item, '');
  /* equivalent to:
  return arr.reduce((a, item) => {
    if (a) {
      // add delimiter before concatenating the next item if the "a" string is not empty
      return a + delim + item;
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  }, '');
  */
}

console.log('should join elements in array together into a string: ',
  join(arrayOfStrings) === 'a,b,c'
);
```

If you know that the `arrayOfStrings` will always contain at least one string, then you can avoid passing the initial value to the `reduce`, and the first item in the array will be used instead, allowing you to unconditionally concatenate the accumulator with a delimiter and the next string:

```js
var arrayOfStrings = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function join(arr, delim = ',') {
  return arr.reduce((a, item) => a + delim + item);
}

console.log('should join elements in array together into a string: ',
  join(arrayOfStrings) === 'a,b,c'
);
```

Comment: appreciate the thorough explanation!

Comment: Follow-up question: In your first example, where do you test for if "a already has something in it?"

Comment: That's the `a ?` - the first part of the conditional operator. If `a` is not empty, it'll evaluate to the first expression in the conditional operator, else it'll evaluate to the second

Comment: hm, don't you need an if statement there? i.e. if (a.length !== 0) type thing?  why does the a  ? test for that?  sorry for being dense

Comment: No, the conditional operator is better when you need an *expression* conditionally, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator It makes the code a lot more concise. `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`

Comment: thx for the link!  I knew of ternary but didn't realize the conditional component of it could be expressed with truthy or falsey statements